# Replacing dataframe column list values with values from another dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to replace data in one of the dataframe while comparing different columns with another data frame with values like below.
I need to map the 'members' column in df1 with 'uid' column in df2 and get the corresponding ipv4-address for one member.

Dataframe 1:

|  | uid | members | type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 42 | afea136c-217f-4b1d-857c-dc4075bxxxxx | [08xx-b8xx- 4bcf-8axx-5f86xxxxxx, 64xx5c4.. | group |

Dataframe 2:

|  | uid | name | ipv4-address | type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 506 | 08xx-b8xx- 4bcf-8axx-5f86xxxxxx | l_re-exx-xx-xx-19.172.211.0m23 | 19.172.211.0 | network |
| 589 | 64xx5c4.. | l_re-exx-xx-xx-19.172.211.0m23 | 19.152.210.0 | network |

is it possible to replace the members column values or jusr create a new column in df1 with ipv4-addresses from df2?

expected outcome:

|  | uid | members | type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 42 | afea136c-217f-4b1d-857c-dc4075bxxxxx | [19.172.211.0, 19.152.210.0,..] | group |

Comment: Please add your expected outcome as your question doesn’t seem to be clear.

Comment: @JonathanLeon I have added the expected outcome in the question.

Comment: Did you try the solution provided? This is what my solution does. It’s not clear what you are needing.

Comment: yes, it does not work for me since we are not mapping the id in df1 members with uid in df2. I just gave the entries as an example and have a lot of rows that I need to map.

Comment: Can you post more data of the two dataframes that aren't truncated? Does the other answer beny provided not work either?

Comment: I have a big file which has list of values in the members column, let me add more data to the question today.
beny's answer gives me  -> nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,

Answer (score 0):

If you are filtering just to the rows you need on df1 and df2, you can do

```
ips = df2['ipv4-address'].tolist()
```

and then set

```
df1['members'] = ips
```

otherwise you'll have to use a little more logic to get the right rows to update

Comment: I need to map the 'members' column in df1 with 'uid' column in df2 and get the corresponding ipv4-address for one member.

Answer (score 0):

Let us try `explode` then `map`

```
df1['new'] = df1.member.explode().map(df2.set_index('name')['ipv4-address']).groupby(level=0).agg(list)
```

Comment: I need to map the 'members' column in df1 with 'uid' column in df2 and get the corresponding ipv4-address for one member.